# How to create dynamic pages in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-nodes

I have contents in the following url:

**mysite.com/project/node-id**

But then i want the user to be directed to

**mysite.com/entries/node-id** when they click on entries link.

How do i achieve this? In the entries page i want to show a view which **takes the node id** from url and shows results accordingly.

Comment: can you elaborate further it will be easier to help you

Comment: @vishal:Well i have got the solution.I have a node A1 created from content type A and i have a view which shows me all the nodes of content type B node-referenced to A1. I placed a link on every 'A' type node page which will take me to a view containing B nodes referenced to A1.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in using arguments with views. http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-arguments .This video exactly represents what i had asked for ! using arguments in views we can create dynamic views of 'page' type display.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create content type(Entries) by CCK
2. Use pathauto, to create desired urls for Entries content type(/entries/[nid]).
3. Then render this new content on project pages(Views, blocks, menus or etc)